# Install component run code in postflight

Tags: joomla-4

in joomla 4.0 beta2-dev, in the postflight method in script.php of my component i have put some code to create menus but at the end of installation of component the postflight isn't executed.

I have tried to put a die() but it has no effect :

```
public function postflight($type, $parent)
{
    $componentinstaller = new MycompnentModelInstall;
    $componentinstaller->createMenu();

    die();
}
```

Why it doens't goes into postflight ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: I’m not fully sure but almost that not only the postflight function but the whole script does not run and the most common reason of that is the name of the script class in your script.php file. We should see your full script file, otherwise we can just guess...

Comment: the component is made with a package, the script.php is this one and it is present into package : https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/blob/K6.0/src/script.php . I haven't changed the postflight part on github branch

Comment: And the preflight function is running from that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you kindly provided the link to the source files, I have downloaded your full Kunena package (6.0 dev.) (for Joomla 4.x.x dev.) just to give it a try and my short conclusion is the following: (well done for this extension, it looks good by the way!)

As I wrote in my first comment I assumed that the problem is caused by the **class** name of the **script file** which is at the moment:

```
class Pkg_KunenaInstaller extends InstallerScript
```

Then I ran a test within the preflight method of the script file but it did not run at all. Then I changed the **script's class name** to the following:

```
class Pkg_KunenaInstallerScript
```

And it runs without a problem. So the simple conclusion is: You do not have to/you cannot extend the **InstallerScript** class in your installer scripts as you did. Probably someone misunderstood or misspelled this at your developer team.

If you extend the base `InstallerScript` class correctly as the following then the inherited methods will work and the installer script will run too:

```
class Pkg_KunenaInstallerScript extends InstallerScript
```

Comment: This requirement is documented here: https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Script_file
quote: _"This file should contain a class named "<element_name>InstallerScript"..."_